# Is it correct to write "$100 \leq x,y \leq 380$"?

Tags: notation, article-writing

I am solving a problem in which I am looking for integers $x$ and $y$ in between $100$ and $380$ (including $100$ and $380$).

Is it mathematically correct to write $$100 \leq x,y \leq 380,$$ or am I supposed to write them separately: $$100 \leq x \leq 380\quad\text{and}\quad 100 \leq y \leq 380 ?$$

Comment: Both notations sounds fine.

Comment: The first one is subject to mis-interpretation, but it is nevertheless used by some authors.

Comment: A less ambiguous alternative would be $x,y\in[100,380].$

Comment: It's very common.

Comment: When specifying cases while defining a function, the first option can get frustratingly hard to disambiguate (I've edited on this site one such example involving $\arctan,$ but can't seem to locate it). $\quad$ I'm not so sure about Anne's suggestion, because it makes $x$ and $y$ look like real numbers more than the inequality notation does (even as they mean exactly the same).

Comment: Write for the convenience of your audience, not for a parser. If someone is troubled by you writing $100\leq x, y\leq 380$, he or she is probably also going to have trouble with anything else you write.

Comment: The ambiguity with the OP's first suggestion is *not* in their simple/trivial example above.

Comment: This is not a question about "mathematical correctness", it is a question about writing so that you will be understood.  The first form is quite common but also potentially ambiguous; if you are very concerned about the potential for your audience to misunderstand, use a less ambiguous alternative like the one you suggest.

Comment: Ann’s suggestion can be interpreted as “x is an arbitrary number, but 100 <= y <= 380”. Actually, if that was what you meant, how would you write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$100 \leq x \leq 380\quad\text{and}\quad 100 \leq y \leq 380 $$ is always unambiguous, while $$100 \leq \quad x,y \quad\leq 380 $$ is seldom misinterpreted.

To incorporate the information about being **integers**:

- The integers $x$ and $y$ are between $100$ and $380,$ inclusive.
- $x,y\in\{100,101,\ldots,380\}$
- $(x,y)\in\{100,101,\ldots,380\}^2$
- $(x,y)\in\left\{m\in\mathbb Z\mid 100\le m\le380 \right\}^2$
- $x,y\in\{m\in\mathbb Z\mid 100\le m\le380 \}$

(Strictly speaking, that listing option isn't definitive, since, for example, those set elements conceivably contains precisely the integers, from $100$ to $380,$ that are indivisible by $3.)$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\{\cdots\}^2$?

Comment: I know what it means, but my brain trips over it.

Comment: @CroCo the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in \{\cdots\}$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC LOL I know how you mean.

Comment: @CroCo It's like how $\mathbb R^2$ means the entire Cartesian plane instead of the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use $ x$ and $y$ for variables that must be integers. It's only a convention, but it's a strong convention.

With that out of the way, my suggestion is

$$m,n \in \{100, 101,... 380\},$$

assuming you've mentioned the integer restriction somewhere previously.

(I might have omitted the $101$, but RyanG used it, and it can't hurt.)